# Spark not isin alternative

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I have a datafame `A` with a ids in column `id`, the entries in this column are a superset of the ids in dataframe `B`.

I'd like to get the complement of the `id`s in dataframe `A` and `B`. So in other words: all the ids from `A` that are not in `B`.

Spark can do this with a filter:

```
A.filter(not('id.isin(B.select('id)))
```

But this doesn't work since `isin` takes varags. Now I can do this:

```
A.filter(not('id.isin(B.select('id)).distinct.collect.map(r => r(0)): _*)
```

But this is quite heavy when using millions of ids since spark cannot distribute this calculation. Is there any way of achieving this complement without the use of `isin`? Perhaps with a join?

Comment: @mtoto correct. That was what I was looking for :). Why is `leftanti` not in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: Also, possible other solution I came up with: `a.join(b, a("id") === b("id"), "left").filter(b("id").isNull)`